Despite using multi-threading for S3 uploads in Spring, why is the execution time still slow?
I am currently modifying a Spring application to implement an API for uploading multiple images to S3 at once using @Async for asynchronous processing with multi-threading to achieve faster responses. However, after implementing this, the response time is not as fast as expected.
The logs indicate that multi-threading is functioning correctly, but the actual S3 upload times are longer, and the overall response is not faster during testing. I understand that S3 can handle concurrent requests, so I am unsure where the issue might be. Could you help identify the problem? Thank you!
Here is the code I wrote and the log output:
@Operation(summary = "다중 이미지 업로드 - 비동기", description = "새로운 이미지를 다중으로 업로드합니다.")
    @PostMapping(value = "/images/async", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ApiResponse<List<String>> uploadMultipleImagesAsync(
            @Parameter(description = "업로드할 이미지 파일들", required = true, schema = @Schema(type = "array", format = "binary"))
            @RequestPart("files") List<MultipartFile> files,
            @Parameter(description = "이미지들이 업로드될 도메인 이름(notice or kindergarten)", required = true)
            @RequestParam("domainName") String domainName) {
        List<String> urls = imageService.uploadImagesAsync(files, domainName);
        return ApiResponse.onSuccess(urls);
    }

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ImageService {
    private final S3Service s3Service;

    // 여러 개의 이미지 업로드 - 비동기
    public List<String> uploadImagesAsync(List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles, String domainName) {
        List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (MultipartFile file : multipartFiles) {
            futures.add(s3Service.uploadImageAsync(file, domainName));
        }

        List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();

        futures.forEach(future ->
                urls.add(future.join())
        );

        return urls;
    }

}

// 이미지 업로드 - 비동기
    @Async("imageUploadExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<String> uploadImageAsync(MultipartFile file, String domainName) {
        CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        String fileName = createFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
        String folder = IMAGES_FOLDER + domainName + "/";

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
        metadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());

        future.complete(uploadToS3(file, folder, fileName));

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("{} - 실행 시간: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(), endTime - startTime);

        return future;
    }

// S3에 업로드 공통 로직
    private String uploadToS3(MultipartFile file, String folder, String fileName) {
        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        objectMetadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
        objectMetadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());

        try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
            amazonS3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, folder + fileName, inputStream,
                objectMetadata).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                "파일 업로드에 실패했습니다.");
        }
        return amazonS3Client.getUrl(bucket, folder + fileName).toString();
    }

@Bean(name = "imageUploadExecutor")
    public Executor imageUploadExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

        executor.setThreadGroupName("imageUploadExecutor");
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.initialize();

        return executor;
    }

async log
synch log
In practice, I expected to see a noticeable improvement in response time with asynchronous processing, but there was no significant difference compared to synchronous processing.
I also tried adjusting the thread pool settings and tested it on a VM rather than locally, but I didn't observe any substantial effect. I really want to understand the cause.

Can you share the number for files and the size of each files you are trying to upload ? Can you also provide the total time taken to upload those files using sync process and async process separately ?
